# CkEditor Not Loading in Iframe in CrossBrowser

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-browser, ckeditor

i have called the ckeditor in iframe, but it is not loading in crossbrowser(other than IE)..

My Calling code is

```
document.getElementById('consFrame').contentWindow.initCustomizedInsideFCKEditor();
```

any help?

Comment: You shared one line of code with us... and this is your private function call ;|. We cannot help you. PS. FCKEditor is extremely old - update it to its successor - http://ckeditor.com

Comment: @Reinmar i just mention method name only initCustomizedInsideFCKEditor, but i already updated ckeditor latest version. My calling method here <code> function initCustomizedInsideFCKEditor(){
 var oFCKeditor = CKEDITOR.replace("editorDescription",{
  height:"160", width:"550"
  }); <code>

Comment: And what does console say? Any error?

Comment: there is no error, but ckeditor not loading fully.